# My second app gives error 910 when I try to install it with the first one

Tags: android, google-play

I have 2 apps on *Google Play*, both are webview Apps.
The first one is "Milana" with the ID `com.milana.eg` going to the website.
The second one is "Milana Stuff" with the ID `com.stuff.milana.eg` going to admin.

Both have a different sign key, but the problem is, that if I installed one of them, I won't be able to install the second one, and it will give a `910` error code!

If I uninstalled one of them, I can install the other one without problems.
I've tested that from 4 different Android devices and they all show the same problem.

Comment: Well the Error 910 happens due to SDCard set as a default storage. I think you need to contact the playstore support for this .

Comment: actually I don't have SD card on any of my testing mobiles :/

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution for this?